# How to show number of children beside dropdown arrow in ag-grid (react) tree data?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-grid in my react project where i have a tree data. Now i want to show the number of children for every parent like the number shown in the screenshot i am attaching.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `suppressCount = false` to `cellRendererParams`

```
<AgGridReact
  treeData
  autoGroupColumnDef={{
    cellRendererParams: { suppressCount: false }
  }}
  ...
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit AgGrid Tree Children Count]

Comment: The screenshot i sent you shows you the parent we are getting from backend. In that json result we are having the ids of children. If ids doesn't exist it means parent doesn't have any child and we won't show any groupContracted/groupExpanded icon (dropdown arrow in that case). Once the use click on this icon we hit the backend to get the children info. Now even before getting the children info i want to show the number of children based on the ids present in parent. SuppressCount: false is not working here as both parent and children are serverside data

Comment: You should include that detail in the question.